# Como inserir formatação CSS no Java Script

Tags: javascript, css

Tenho o seguinte código Java Script:

```
status.text('Enviando...');
```

Como faço para formatar esta informação que será escrita na tela com CSS?

Código completo:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajaxupload.3.5.js" ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function(){
        var btnUpload=$('#upload');
        var status=$('#status');
        new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
            // Arquivo que fará o upload
            action: 'upload-file.php?cliente=<?php echo $cliente; ?>&cod=<?php echo $cod; ?>',
            //Nome da caixa de entrada do arquivo
            name: 'uploadfile',

            onSubmit: function(file, ext){
                 if (! (ext && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/.test(ext))){ 
                    // verificar a extensão de arquivo válido
                    status.text('Somente JPG, PNG ou GIF são permitidas');
                    return false;
                }
                status.text('Enviando...');
                status.
            },
            onComplete: function(file, response){
                //Limpamos o status
                status.text('');
                //Adicionar arquivo carregado na lista
                if(response==="success"){
                    $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').html('<strong>Foto inserida com sucesso!').addClass('success');
                } else{
                    $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').html('<strong>Foto inserida com sucesso!').addClass('success');
                }
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use os atributos do objeto `style` do elemento `status`.

Por exemplo, para trocar a cor do texto para vermelho em VanillaJS, utilize:

```
status.style.color = "#f00";
```

No framework jQuery:

```
status.css("color", "#f00");
```

Comment: Funcionou não. Utilizei o mesmo código que me passou. Não existe o objeto STYLE.

Comment: Você esta usando framework jQuery?

Comment: Veja codigo completo que postei

Comment: Perfeito, esta usando o jQuery. Veja minha edição.

Comment: Para aumentar a fonte? Pois coloquei status.css("size", "30px"); e não funcionou.

Comment: Use `status.css("font-size","30px")`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34605/discussion-between-gladison-neuza-perosini-and-filipe).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode também  deixar pré-configurado no seu style.css exemplo:

```js
var status = $(".status");
status.text('Enviando...');
```

```css
.status {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="status"></div>
```

Veja funcionando no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/sma62uq5/)